# Как передать HttpContext классу перед вызовом метода контроллера?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Читал статью на [Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/176043/), после прочтения ничего не понял и голова идёт кругом. Думаю попробовать написать свой класс и куда попроще. Только вот как передать класс HttpContext перед вызовом метода контроллера?

Comment: Статья старенькая, сейчас используется Identity. http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Контекст текущего HTTP запроса должен быть доступен через статическое свойство:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current
```

Примеры есть в официальной [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx).